# Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::__construct()

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5, postman

I have this error that says:

**Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\satusehat2\app\Http\Controllers\PasienController.php on line 68.**

This is my function

```
public function curl_postman() {
        $client = new Client();
        $headers = [
          'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
          'Authorization' => 'My Bearer token'
        ];
        $body = '';
        $request = new Request('GET', 'my-api-address', $headers, $body);
        $res = $client->sendAsync($request)->wait();
        echo $res->getBody();
        
    }
```

and the line 68 is

```
$body = '';
```

Comment: The error is coming from `new Request` line and not `$body` one. The error means that Request constructor expects array as first parameter and you're sending a string. 

Take a look at here to see what is expected https://pkp.sfu.ca/ojs/doxygen/master/html/classSymfony_1_1Component_1_1HttpFoundation_1_1Request.html#a301618654ad4ca76fb3c5463c1dd6dd7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::create()` instead which implicitly calls a request factory and returns you a `Request` object.

```
$request = Request::create(uri: 'my-api-address', content: $body, server: $headers)
```

PS: You do not need to explicitly specify the `method` parameter as `'GET'` is the default value.